# I need help setting up a connection for digitalocean managed database in laravel

Tags: laravel

I created a mysql cluster and I have been having issues setting up a connection between the database and my project.

Answer (score 0):

Create DB and User within DigitalOcen 
 and then run the command below :

GRANT ALL ON DB_NAME TO 'USER_NAME'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ALTER USER 'USER_NAME' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'GIVE_THE_PASSWORD';

Laravel Connection :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=As given on DO managed DB
DB_PORT=As given on DO managed DB
DB_DATABASE=give the name of the database that you created within DO and want to use here
DB_USERNAME=give the name of the user that you created within DO and want to use here
DB_PASSWORD=give the pass of the database that has been created automatically while create DB
```